# Group by year and month with given date range using Lambda or LINQ Query

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda

I have a List with the following type of objects. The list currently in ascending order.

```
public class ReportsCountByDate{
    public int  CountOfReports { get ; set ;}
    public DateTime ReportGeneratedDate { get ;set ;}  
}
```

My Data Set:

```
CountOfReports     ReportGeneratedDate
3                  2017-02-07
5                  2017-02-21
5                  2017-03-12
1                  2017-05-03
4                  2017-05-23
3                  2017-06-12
```

[Please note that there is no repot for 2017 April]
If I need to get report count from 2017 January to 2017 July.

```
CountOfReports  YearAndMonth 
0               2017-01 
8               2017-02
5               2017-03
0               2017-04
5               2017-05
3               2017-06
0               2017-07
```

Can someone point me out how to get following result using `Lambda` or `LINQ` query.

Update :

Here is my code.

```
var startYear = input.durationStartDate.Year;
var startMonth = input.durationStartDate.Month;

var endYear = input.durationEndDate.Year;
var endMonth = input.durationEndDate.Month;

var yearRange = (endYear - startYear) == 0 ? 1 : (endYear - startYear);

var monthRange = ((input.durationEndDate.Year - input.durationStartDate.Year) * 12 + input.durationEndDate.Month - input.durationStartDate.Month) == 0 ? 1 : ((input.durationEndDate.Year - input.durationStartDate.Year) * 12 + input.durationEndDate.Month - input.durationStartDate.Month);



var desposition = await _dispositionSummaryManager.GetDispositionFormByCreateDate(input.platform, input.durationStartDate, input.durationEndDate);

var changesPerYearAndMonth =
                   from year in Enumerable.Range(startYear, yearRange)
                   from month in Enumerable.Range(startMonth, monthRange)
                   let key = new { Year = year, Month = month }
                   join ReportsCountByDate in desposition on key
                             equals new
                             {
                                 ReportsCountByDate.ReportGeneratedDate.Year,
                                 ReportsCountByDate.ReportGeneratedDate.Month
                             } into g
                   select new { GroupCriteria = key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Comment: can you try first

Comment: suggest **refactor your data structure** to simplify linq. in `My Data Set`, add two properties of `Year` and`Month`, and all your input values can also be year and month.

Comment: @LeiYang  Thank you. Any suggestion for how to set given date range to this?

Comment: your key problem is not linq, it's date calculations. you can  encapsule the complexity by adding some methods/properties and/or separate  month and year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the current input

```
var startDate = new DateTime(startYear, startMonth, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(endYear, endMonth + 1, 1).AddMinutes(-1);

var months = new List<DateTime>();
var dt = startDate;
while (dt < endDate) {
    months.Add(dt);
    dt = dt.AddMonths(1);
}

var result = from month in months
             let key = new { month.Year, month.Month }
             join report in desposition
             on key equals new { report.ReportGeneratedDate.Year, report.ReportGeneratedDate.Month } into g
             select new {
                 YearAndMonth = string.Format("{0}-{1:D2}", key.Year, key.Month),
                 CountOfReports = g.Sum(n => n.CountOfReports)
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy` uses [`Lookup` to get the groups](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs.html#a031838be1c3b532).

```
var lookup = desposition.ToLookup(_ => _.ReportGeneratedDate.Year * 100 
   + _.ReportGeneratedDate.Month, _ => _.CountOfReports);

var result = Enumerable.Range(201701, 12)
            .Select(_ => new { CountOfReports = lookup[_].Sum(), YearAndMonth = _ });
```

Comment: are you perl guy to use `_`?